# relations between the moments of random variable

Tags: probability

For a positive random variable, how to prove the relations between its moments:

$EX^4\leq(EX^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}(EX^5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

For discrete random variables, the relation is true since we can use the following inequality:

$a^2+b^2\geq2ab.$
Then we can extend the relation to all random variables. Is there other direct way to prove the relation(not from discrete random variable to continuous random variable)?

Comment: Since $X>0$, it is just a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (no matter if $X$ is a continuous random variable or a discrete one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Hölder’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure) $$\mathbb{E}[AB]\le(\mathbb{E}[A^p])^{\frac{1}{p}}(\mathbb{E}[B^q])^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ where $p$ and $q$ satisfy$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

You should select $p=q=2$, $A=X^{\frac{3}{2}}$, and $B=X^{\frac{5}{2}}$ to acquire the desired inequality.

Comment: Sorry but Hölder for $p=q=2$ is widely known under another name...

Comment: @SHAN you may use the Cauchy-Schwarz with the given $A$ and $B$ as well.